# How can I get image's name?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-resources

I want to make a function which debug when image's name equal "aaa". So I think that I should get image's name.

for example, there is a `ImageView`.

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.button);

public void passMSg(){
   if(name == "button"){ // "name" means image's name. = button
      Toast. ~
   }
```

I find other questions. But I can't understand and I think that is not answer which I want. Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your image is a file like 'aaa.jpg/png..'

try to use the APIs of String such as `subString().indexOf()`

and your code may be like this:

```
int index = name.indexOf(".");

String name = name.subString(name,0,index);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assigned a tag for your ImageView then you can get it like this

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/imageView" 
   android:tag="aaa" />
```

```
ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewbyId(R.id.img);
String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(v.getTag());
```